# Plotting PMF neatly in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a library that would help me to neatly plot a probability mass function of a sample in python, like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415455/plotting-probability-density-function-by-sample-with-matplotlib

Comment: I am also looking for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Via matplotlib.pyplot's stem module**

> matplotlib.pyplot.stem(*args, **kwargs)

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import stem

stem(y, linefmt='b-', markerfmt='bo', basefmt='r-')
stem(x, y, linefmt='b-', markerfmt='bo', basefmt='r-')
```

**or closer to the metal**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0.1, 2*pi, 10)
markerline, stemlines, baseline = stem(x, cos(x), '-.')
setp(markerline, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')
setp(baseline, 'color','r', 'linewidth', 2)

show()
```

[image]

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think this one is neat enough,

[image]

This is the code:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


xk = np.arange(7)
pk = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2)
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(xk, pk))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(xk, custm.pmf(xk), 'ro', ms=8, mec='r')
ax.vlines(xk, 0, custm.pmf(xk), colors='r', linestyles='-', lw=2)
plt.title('Custom made discrete distribution(PMF)')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.show()
```

Ref, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html