# Distribution of outcomes in dice experiments

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, histogram, distribution

So I wrote a short Python function to plot distribution outcome of dice experiments. It's working fine but when I run for example `dice(1,5000)`
or `dice(10,5000)` or `dice(100,5000)` the histograms shows a skewed distribution (high preference for 6). However, the average shows the to-be expected value of around `3.5`. I thought maybe this has sth to do with the random number generation so I tried out 2 methods: 1st with `random.randint` and the 2nd one is as in code. However, they deliver similar results. Like there is something wrong with the upper limit. But I'm not sure why there is such a skewed distribution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

# Throw a dice
def dice(N,n):
    result = np.zeros((n,N))
    '''
    N: number of dices
    n: number of experiment
    '''
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(N):
            random_number = random.random()
            outcome = int(random_number * 6 + 1)
            result[i][j]=outcome
    laverage = np.mean(result)

    print('Result of throwing %d dice(s) for %d times:'%(N,n),result)
    print(laverage)
    plt.hist(np.resize(result,(N*n,1)),bins=[x for x in range(1,7)])
    plt.xlabel('Outcome')
    plt.ylabel('Number of occurences')
    plt.show()

dice(1,5000)
```

Comment: Nice job posting an MCVE

Comment: Histograms aren't really appropriate for plotting probability mass functions for the very reasons highlighted by your problem and the answers given below.  You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28484444/2166798 for some nice alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Your plot is only showing 5 bars - the bar is to the right of the number, so I believe the results for `5` and `6` are being combined. If you change to `range(1,8)` you see more of what you expect.

[image]

Comment: By setting the bin boundaries to the same integers as the samples, you constantly run into the possibility of rounding errors. Setting the boundaries at a safe distance, such as `[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ...]` makes sure every sample falls into the correct bin.

Comment: The main difference between this solution and mine (aside from its simplicity), is that the bars are still labeled on the left rather than the center. For a discrete distribution, labelling the edges is arguably more misleading.

Answer (score 3):

According to a sample of your code, the issue is a plotting problem, not a computational one, which is why you are seeing the correct mean. As you can see, the following image shows five bars, the last one being twice the size of the others:

[image: pic]

Notice also that the bars are labeled on the left, and there is therefore no "6" bar. This has to do with what [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) means by `bins`:

> If *bins* is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin; in this case, bins may be unequally spaced. All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open.

So to specify bin edges, you probably want something more like

```
plt.hist(np.ravel(result), bins=np.arange(0.5, 7.5, 1))
```

And the result:

[image]

**Unasked Questions**

If you want to simulate `N * n` data points, you can use numpy directly. Replace your original initialization of `result` and the `for` loop with any of the following lines:

```
result = (np.random.uniform(size=(n, N)) * 6 + 1).astype(int)
result = np.random.uniform(1.0. 7.0, size=(n, N)).astype(int)
result = np.random.randint(1, 7, size=(n, N))
```

The last line is preferable in terms of efficiency and accuracy.

Another possible improvement is in how you compute the histogram. Right now, you are using `plt.hist`, which calls [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html). For small integers like you have, [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) is arguably a much better binning technique:

```
count = np.bincount(result.ravel())[1:]
plt.bar(np.arange(1, 7), count)
```

Notice that this also simplifies the plotting since you specify the centers of the bars directly, instead of having `plt.hist` guess it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lazy (like me), you can also use numpy to directly generate a matrix and [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) to deal with bins for you:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

dices = 1000
throws = 5000
x = np.random.randint(6, size=(dices, throws)) + 1
sns.distplot(x)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Seaborn usually make good choices, which can save a bit of time in configuration. That's worth a try at least. You can also use the `kde=False` option on the seaborn plot to get rid of the density estimate.

Just for the sake of it and to show how seaborn behave, the same with the sum over 100 dices:

```py
dices = 100
throws = 5000
x = np.random.randint(6, size=(dices, throws)) + 1
sns.distplot(x.sum(axis=0), kde=False)
```

[image]